# CommandError: App 'books' has migrations. Only the sqlmigrate and sqlflush commands can be used when an app has migrations

Tags: python, django

I am trying to learn about `python-django`.
I want to make self app named books.

When I ran this command

```
$ python manage.py sqlall books
```

Following error arises

> CommandError: App 'books' has migrations. Only the sqlmigrate and sqlflush commands can be used when an app has migrations.

I did not understand why this error arise and what does it mean? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Which dkango version out of curiosity?

Answer (score 0):

After typing `python manage.py sqlall --help` I get the following:

`Prints the CREATE TABLE, custom SQL and CREATE INDEX SQL statements for the given model module name(s).`

It prints the SQL that is used to create these tables. As they already exists, Django doesn't print them and instructs to use `sqlmigrate` (print SQL for a specific migration) or `sqlflush` (print SQL which returns tables to their initial state).

Answer (score 0):

From django documentation of [`sqlall`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/django-admin/#sqlall-appname-appname)

> **django-admin.py sqlall**
>
> Prints the CREATE TABLE and initial-data SQL statements for the given
>   app name(s).

In later versions of django starting from 1.7, you can do the same with this:

`python manage.py sqlmigrate appname migration_name`

As you are following along the django tutorial, for your case this will be

`python manage.py sqlmigrate books 0001`

This worked for me in django 1.8. You can read more from the documentation of [`sqlmigrate`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/django-admin/#sqlmigrate-app-label-migrationname)

> **django-admin sqlmigrate**
>
> Prints the SQL for the named migration. This requires an active database connection, which it will use to resolve constraint names; this means you must generate the SQL against a copy of the database you wish to later apply it on.

Comment: How will I find the `migration name`?

Comment: You can find all your migrations in the `project/app/migrations` folder.

Comment: Thank you.  
I found this command as well `python manage.py migrate --list`

Comment: Just an FYI: the --list no longer works in newer versions of django.  Instead, you have to run "./manage.py showmigrations"